# Showing the most, second most, and third most occurring values

Tags: filter, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Which formula shows unique (text) values of Column A, and the corresponding most occurring values (text) from Column B and sorts them on degree of appearance over different columns?

I already know how to show only the first most occurring values, but not the second, third and so on.

The formula which only shows the first most occurring values:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A;A:A<>""));QUERY({A:B\A:A};"select Col1, Col2, count(Col3) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1, Col2 order by count(Col3) desc");{1\2};0))
```

[Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DBmlkLzEj8rPZdesv5GHc5abZztr087wwE9VYJeI14U/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a combination of QUERY and INDEX pulled across

```
=iferror(index(query($A$1:$C$100, "select B,count(C) where A contains '"&$E2&"' group by B order by count(C) desc",1) ,columns($AA:AB),1),"")
```

where the media type is in E2.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tom, I did use your formula on my own test set, replaced the "," with ";" because of my language settings, but the outcome does not come in different columns but on different rows.
I figured the problem is somewhere in the COLUMN formula, I think?

Comment: [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DBmlkLzEj8rPZdesv5GHc5abZztr087wwE9VYJeI14U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've had a look at the test sheet. Should have said that you need to add extra columns to the spreadsheet starting with AA to make it work!

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom, I understand now why it didn't work. But why must the COLUMN formula have a range of multiple empty rows?

Comment: It's just a way of getting a number which starts at 2 and increases as you go across, but if you choose to use columns it's best to avoid any areas of the spreadsheet that you might use for formulae in case you get a circular reference. But it would have been better if I had used =iferror(index(query($A$2:$C$100, "select B,count(C) where A contains '"&$E2&"' group by B order by count(C) desc",1) ,columns($E$1:F$1),1),"") for intance rather than using entire columns.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED (Following clarification of the question and some improvements to ensure the answer stands alone, without reference to external spreadsheets)

I use a combination of "`FILTER()`", "`UNIQUE()`" and "`SORT()`", in conjunction with the calculated frequencies (determined using `COUNTIFS`).  See the sample sheet below, [taken from yours](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZLRUwHkRQyX9iqvbqkNq_D5vgvKQwFadmmhwfAVlosA/edit#gid=0).

It's not a single cell formula, but it's simple and easy to understand.

The spreadsheet is structured as below:
[image]

Channels are in column A, the associated media are in column B, and the frequency of a given (Channel, Media) pair is in Column C given by, (in C2, for example)

```
=countifs($B$2:$B;"=" &B2;$A$2:$A;"=" & A2)
```

Then make a list of unique media using `=UNIQUE(B2:B)`. Adjacent to a given unique medium (say, in cell F13), I then determine all the pairings related to that chosen medium and create an array ordered by the most frequent such pairing:

```
=transpose(unique(transpose(array_constrain(transpose(sort(filter($A$2:$C;$B$2:$B=F13);3;FALSE));1;10))))
```

This works by filtering out all pairs (with the pair frequencies) for the chosen medium (selected in F13), sorts the list by the pair frequency (i.e., the 1st, 2nd, 3rd most recurring media), trims the array to display only media, and then removes repeated entries (since we have one repeated entry each time a given pairing is repeated, i.e., seen more than more than once).  `Transpose` is used because `Unique` didn't work with a row array, only a column array.

The formula works for any additional channels and media added to columns A and B respectively.

The "10" un the formula refers to the number of columns retained during `array_constrain()` and can be made arbitrarily high.

**Modifications to Original Posting:**
In order to make this work, I had to swap the media and channels columns with each other in the original answer, and then add a column C which was the frequency of that pairing, which I later used to sort the 1st, 2nd, etc.. most popular channels.

Comment: I should also note that I added an extra column to count the frequency.

Comment: No, what I want as outcome is the most populair channels, (and also the second most populair channels, third most populair channels, etc.) for each unique medium.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect that new information

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer Paul. One thing is not clear for me.. Why did you have to switch the media and channels columns? And do you have a way to make it work without switching the columns?

Comment: It was to do with the way array_constrain works.  It doesn't allow arbitrary trimming of the arrays, but only allows the first N rows or columns to be selected.  The way the sheet was setup meant that I had to swap channels and media to ensure the column I wanted remained after the array_constrain.

Comment: Taking Tom Sharpe's answer above as a model of a good answer, I've updated my own, not in the hope it will accepted as the answer here, but more in the hope it will prove a useful alternative to others looking at thus question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, for a single cell formula, try query()

```
=query(A:B; "select A, count(B) where A<>'' group by A label count(B) 'Frequency'"; 1)
```

Comment: Thanks but what I want as outcome are the most populair channels, (and also the second most populair channels, third most populair channels, etc.) for each unique medium.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood. Please check out Tom's solution and see if that works for you.